# How to simply update specific timestamps in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I'm having a hard time finding an example of just making a simple update function to update the time in my timestamp column in any row that contains my `$username` variable. Any ideas how I could make this work?

```
class updateUserData {

    public function __construct() {
        mysql_connect("mysql.mymysql.com", "admin", "password");
        mysql_select_db("my_db");
    }

    function userUpdate($username) {
        return mysql_query("UPDATE mytable WHERE username = '$username' SET timestamp = 'NOW()'");
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  What undesired effect is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"UPDATE mytable SET timestamp = NOW() WHERE username = '$username' "
```

skip '' around NOW() and provide correct order of UPDATE SET WHERE

Answer (score 3):

Reverse the order of your update. See [MySQL UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

```
UPDATE   mytable
SET      timestamp = NOW()
WHERE    username = 'username'
```

Also, [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) is a function, so don't enclose it in quotes.